# python multiprocessing + paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, paramiko

I am trying to send command to a list of computing nodes. `info` is the class object to keep track of all my global parameters. My problem is that when I have over 10 nodes, some will fail to execute the command. Some say I need to use `multiprocessing` but I am not sure how to use that module.

Here is my code:

```
import os, sys, threading, paramiko 
import getpass
import myData


def callout(info, command):
    outlock = threading.Lock()
    print("\n\n")
    username = input("user name = ")
    password = getpass.getpass("password = ")
    main(info, outlock, username, password, command)


def main(info, outlock, username, password, command):
    threads = []
    info.elfstdout = []
    info.elfstderr = []
    for h in info.nodes: #info.nodes is a list of hostname strings.
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h, outlock, username, password, command, info,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def workon(host, outlock, username, password, command, info):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print(host, "\n\n\tConnection Failed!\n")
        quit()

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)

    with outlock:
        stdoutnote = '{} {}'.format(host,  stdout.readlines())
        stderrnote = '{} {}'.format(host,  stderr.readlines())
        print("stdout  ", stdoutnote)
        print("stderr  ", stderrnote)
        info.elfstdout.append(stdoutnote)
        info.elfstderr.append(stderrnote)


info.nodes = ['host1', 'host2', ...]
command = ". .bash_profile; python myOtherModule.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have threads in the way you might expect. Ultimately Python will only ever run one thread (you can search for the Global Interpreter Lock) to learn more about this.

However, you *can* run multiple Python processes, which is the purpose of the multiprocessing module. `multiprocessing.Pool` handles a number of worker processes. Calling `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` takes a function and a list of arguments. The [first example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) in the documentation shows this. If you have multiple arguments that need to be passed to the worker function, you should bundle them into a list of tuples.

For example:

```
def do_work(args):
    arg1, arg2, arg3 = args
    # do whatever

def main():
    work_args = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), ... ]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    p.map(do_work, work_args)
```